# Select css selector using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I am working on a webscraper using html requests and beautiful soup (I am new to this). For multiple webpages e.g. (https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/cat/hermes-rose-herms-silky-blush-6g_R03752945/?previewAttribute=32%20Rose%20Pommette) I am trying to grab the image link, which is always in the same for multiple webpages. The HTML is:

```
<img class="c-image-gallery__img" src="//images.selfridges.com/is/image/selfridges/R03752945_32ROSEPOMMETTE_M?$PDP_M_ZOOM$" loading="lazy">
```

I have tried to use the CSS selector:

```
r = scraper.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
imagelink = soup.select('body > section > section.c-product-hero.--multiple-product-shot > div.c-product-hero__product-shots.c-image-gallery > div > picture:nth-child(1) > img')
```

which returns `None`

or find_all:

```
soup.find_all('img')
```

But the specific link is not in the list. I am unsure why this is. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: _“I am unsure why this is.”_ - because the HTML returned by that URL, does not contain this element. Which in all likelihood means, it gets loaded and inserted into the document later, via client-side JavaScript. Which means, if you want to scrape this kind of content, you can not do it by just requesting the initial source code of the page, you would much rather need what’s called a _headless browser_.

Comment: Thank you for this, the reason I have not been ablie to is a cloudflare has blocked access when trying to access the page via html-requests. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: What does this have to do with Cloudflare? Load the page in your browser, view the actual source code (_not_ the DOM inspector view) - the element you want, is not in there.

Answer (score 1):

This page you are trying to scrape uses Cloudflare and it has some kind of protection from being scraped. The server returns a "403 Forbidden" HTTP status code. Some websites use a lot of javascript and these are also hard to scrape without a javascript capable browser. I would suggest you use a different technology like [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

link = "https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36 OPR/75.0.3969.171"}

page = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
print(page.status_code)
print(page.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
soup_imgs = soup.find_all("img")
for img in soup_imgs:
    print(img)
```